# Get a specific Redhat version with regard to Kernel version

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel

I have to install RHEL(Red Hat Enterprise Linux) with kernel version 2.6.26.8. I dont know what RHEL I have to download to get this kernel version. Any suggestion??

Comment: For those who may get confused like, the kernel version has nothing to do with the RHEL version. Of cousre every RHEL comes in a different kernel version from before, but you cannot find a RHEL with your preferred Kernel version. You have to update/ install your preferred kernel afterwards. In my case I downloaded and installed RHEL 5.11. I then installed the 2.6.26 kernel. After applying the 2.6.26.8 patch I finally got my correct setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RHEL stands for **R**ed **H**at **E**nterprise **L**inux.

you can get the version and kernel details by uname command like the below example:

```
[hatem@localhost ~]$ uname -a

Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 04:27:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

if you want to know what is the distribution is:

```
[hatem@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/issue

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

Comment: Well I already know what you said! I want to know which RHEL version I have to download to get that specific version of kernel?? Right now I can select any version of RHEL for download but I don't know which one I have to download to get that specific kernel version. I tried to find the version history but I couldn't find an answer for my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this link https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078. 
But for **kernel version 2.6.26.8** I think you need to update kernel version manually.

Comment: Yes, this what I did eventually.